# How to track if document is printed or canceled

Tags: vb.net, xslt, webforms, visual-studio-2005

I am using xslt to show a report and opening the print option at the same time. I wants to update some data if the user clicks on print. That's why i wants to track if user clicked on print or cancel.

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
window.focus();
 window.print();
</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lblError"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Xml ID="xmlPrintDigiRenewal" runat="server"></asp:Xml>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Server Code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Try
Dim objXslTrans As New Xsl.XslTransform
Dim inputXml As New XmlDocument
inputXml.LoadXml(Session("User_Profile").ToString())
objXslTrans.Load(Server.MapPath("../Xslt/RL_DGCertSign.xslt"))
xmlPrintDigiRenewal.Document = inputXml 
xmlPrintDigiRenewal.Transform = objXslTrans
Catch ex As Exception
lblError.Text = ex.Message
End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Show us the code where you open the report/printing

Comment: So where is the cancel button?

Comment: Whenever you try to print a document from your system. A window pops-up, where you select the printer and then press print. I am talking about that window when opened via code.